# Is there a way to actually delete the posts I deleted?

Tags: support, deletion

Well, the question is clear. I deleted some answers I myself wrote because they missed the point or were stupid or simply lacked some thing I considered important. Those answers aren't deleted at all and they form a tail into my account. I am pretty sure I won't need them for anything never.

I undeleted some questions because I could recover them and I considered they are good enough, so it seems to me a good idea have something like a trash bin, but one I can empty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Deletions on this site are soft-deletions. You cannot delete posts in a more firm way than you already did. Deleted posts will stay visible to you, moderators and users with sufficiently many points. Moreover, these posts can have an impact on the account, e.g., they can contribute to automatic posting-restrictions.

In very exceptional cases posts can be disassociated from an account. They would then be no longer linked to the account that asked them. This is however more common for undeleted posts.

If you posted something that absolutely must be firmly deleted, for example to disseminate the information would create some major risk or concern, say, you accidentally posted confidential data, then moderators have tools to deal with this (flag the post and explain the situation).

Regarding the trash-bin emptying analogy. The user-interface makes it quite difficult to even get to ones own deleted posts, especially to older ones. In that sense the bin is emptied.

Comment: Thank you very much. No, my post are simply low quality, nothing more than a little embarrasing :) And once, revisiting some topics I had the experience to see one of those deleted posts...

Comment: @RafaBudría "my post are simply low quality" then improve and undelete them! :)

Comment: Heh. They completely missed the point, unrecoverables :)

Comment: @RafaBudría What a lot of people do is to edit their deleted posts to remove everything and just put in `..................................`.  People with high enough rep to be able to see your deleted posts can still look up what used to be there by clicking the "edited [this date] at [this time]" link, but I can't see any reason why someone would bother.  So this method effectively erases any embarrassing posts.

Comment: @Bye_World Thank you for the idea.

Comment: @RafaBudría No worries.  I've had my share of embarrassing posts as well.  The real trouble is when OP *accepts* it. :-\

Comment: @Bye_World I do not agree this is a good idea in general. First editing an answer post will bump the thread drawing attention to it, second  I for one am more likely to pay attention to some blanked post than to a non blanked one.

Comment: @RafaBudría see my comment above. This blanking is not a goodidea IMO.

Comment: @quid TBH, neither of those are convincing reasons to me.  Bumping a thread every once in a while (and it's not like anyone blanks their posts on a daily basis) isn't really a big deal.  Especially during a busy time of day where the bumped thread will soon disappear.  And I imagine you're in the minority of people if you actually check what the post was before being blanked.  I occasionally read deleted posts, but the only time I've ever had the desire to see what was there before a post was blanked was when the comments below it said it was really rude (so of course I was curious ;} ).